# software for mathematical animations

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software, online-resources

What is a good software to make mathematical animations?

It would be good if is not necessary to micromanage.

I mean this [kind of animations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:LucasVB/Gallery)

At this time of the XXI century, should be some software specifically made for this.

I need to animate fractals, because I have difficulty visualizing some concepts.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems - many of those are up to the task.

Comment: GeoGebra is the simplest to use. Also try the physics animation software  algodoo. Both free.

Comment: Geogebra is quite good and easy to use. You can have a look at a video that I made https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMlRYJmjYN8